# cppcms session vanish with each request

Tags: session, cppcms

When I use

```
cppcms::service(argc, argv);
booster::intrusive_ptr c = new myApp(service);
service.applications_pool().mount(c);
service.run();
```

instead of

```
cppcms::service(argc, argv);
service.applications_pool().mount(cppcms::applications_factory<myApp>());
service.run();
```

sessions clear with each new request.
Is it a bug?

Answer (score 1):

No, the behavior of sessions of synchronous and asynchronous apps is different

See: https://sourceforge.net/p/cppcms/bugs/93/

Comment: Thank you. I tested `session()["key"] = value;` and then `session().save()`. But when I call `session().load()` nothing is loaded. What skhoud I do?